# Ms Access 2010 issue with a where clause in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a complex `select` statement for an Access 2010 database which grabs data from multiple tables using several `LEFT JOIN` statements. The query works as expected and I get the entire table.

So now I want to add search functionality.
One way was to add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query and reference one of the `JOIN`ed tables' text field and compare it against some text (`WHERE [All Names].Name LIKE "*Mark*"`).

Second option I tried was `select * from (**complex sql here**) where **condition**`

Now in both cases, when my condition is something simple like `([ID]<15)`, it works like a charm, but when I change it to `([Employee Name] LIKE "\*Mark\*")` or the one in option 1, it produces an empty data table as if the request goes through, there is no error or exception, all the field names are present, but no rows are returned.

However, if I grab the full string of the generated SQL string (either option) using the debugger (or just dump it into a text file), and then with literally no changes put that string directly into a new Access query, it works fine and returns several fields where the name contains "Mark"

Very simply put, a query that works fine within Access, does not work from within C#.

So I am now confused

Comment: can you show your query

Comment: For Access.. is an asterisk the wildcard? Or a percentage sign?

Comment: If the query in fact *does* work in access but not through the c# driver, then perhaps you need to look at your driver.  It may be interpreting your sql differently than access does.  What driver are you using?

Comment: Update the question with related Code

Comment: The issue probably revolves around the differences between SQL & Jet SQL, and may also involve how you are communicating between C# & the database. As Bew said, you will need to show your query - including the "complex" bit, and I'd suggest also including the C# you're using to invoke it. Without this stuff, it's likely no-one will be able to give you a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using OleDb to connect to the Access db file.  In that situation you must use ANSI wild cards (`%` and `_`) for a `Like` comparison instead of `*` and `?`.

Use a pattern like this in your `WHERE` clause.

```sql
WHERE [Employee Name] LIKE "%Mark%"
```

If you want a query which works the same within an Access session as it does from an OleDb connection, use `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE`.  `ALIKE` always uses the ANSI wild cards.

```sql
WHERE [Employee Name] ALIKE "%Mark%"
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp. I did not know that wildcards were different when using OleDB.

Answer (score 1):

Simon's question and HansUp's answer ended up solving my problem.
For those curious or having a similar problem, here is full query:

```
string query=
  "SELECT Employees.ID, " +
  "[All Names E].Name AS [Employee Name], " +
  "Titles.Title, " +
  "[All Names S].Name AS [Supervisor Name], " +
  "Employees.[Phone #], " +
  "Offices.[Office Location], " +
  "PCs.PC " +
  "FROM (((((Employees LEFT JOIN [All Names] as [All Names E] ON Employees.Employee = [All Names E].ID) " +
  "LEFT JOIN [All Names] as [All Names S] on Employees.Supervisor=[All Names S].ID) " +
  "LEFT JOIN Titles on Employees.Title=Titles.ID) " +
  "LEFT JOIN Offices on Employees.[Office Location]=Offices.ID) " +
  "LEFT JOIN PCs on Employees.PC=PCs.ID) " +
  "ORDER BY Employees.ID";
```

Adding a where clause before `ORDER BY` that is `WHERE ([All Names E].Name LIKE \"*Mark*\")` did work from within Access.
The second way was:

```
string searchQuery="select * from ("+query+") where ([Employee Name] like \"*Mark*\")";
```

Both methods worked perfectly in Access, but I had no idea there was a different wildcard symbol for use with OleDB.

So changing the asterisk to a percentage sign fixed the issue.

Thanks again.