# Data in Excel with OLEDB connection from access don't update when use LIKE operator

Tags: excel, ms-access, connection, ms-office, oledb

When I use LIKE operator in a Query in Access and I create a OLEDB connection in Excel to import this data to Excel, the data don't update even after change the query with another filter. Is like if I had not changed the query with the new filter.

I can solve this taking this query and adding a INTO TempTable and linking this temptable in a OLEDB connection in excel. In this case the changes are reflected, but the query directly not.

**Query**

```
SELECT tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO, 
       tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD,
       tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica, 
       tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria, 
       tb_fechamento_ddd.Qtd
FROM tb_fechamento_ddd
WHERE (((tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO)>=#3/1/2014#) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD)="93") 
AND (((tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*GSM*" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*CDMA*" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*LTE*")) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria)="Pre")) 
OR (((tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO)>=#3/1/2014#) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD)="93") 
AND (((tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*GSM*" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*CDMA*" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Like "*LTE*") 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Like "Migra*") 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria) Like "*Pré*"));
```

P.S: Sorry by excessive parenthesis, and duplicated filters in Where clause, but the access don't work Appropriately if I don't use this.

Comment: The issue here is the same as [this c# question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18732337/77335)

Comment: Great! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on post cited by HansUp:

I change every LIKE to ALIKE operator and change * of Access pattern by % of ANSI pattern.

Then:

```
SELECT tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO, 
   tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD,
   tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica, 
   tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria, 
   tb_fechamento_ddd.Qtd
FROM tb_fechamento_ddd
WHERE (((tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO)>=#3/1/2014#) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD)="93") 
AND (((tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%GSM%" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%CDMA%" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%LTE%")) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria)="Pre")) 
OR (((tb_fechamento_ddd.PERIODO)>=#3/1/2014#) 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.DDD)="93") 
AND (((tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%GSM%" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%CDMA%" 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Not Alike "%LTE%") 
And (tb_fechamento_ddd.metrica) Alike "Migra%") 
AND ((tb_fechamento_ddd.categoria) Alike "%Pré%"));
```

Another bugs of Access Query on Excel that I get solutions:

- Queries made with UNION don't is showed on list of queries on create a connection in Excel:

Create a SubQuery to "shelter" the query with Unions:

```
Select * from table_A
UNION ALLL
Select * from table_B
```

to

```
Select * from 
(Select * from table_A
UNION ALLL
Select * from table_B) as SubQryUnion
```

Another bug:
If you use on field with a aggregate function a alias that have a same name that a field of table and use this alias in a expression field, the query doesn't is showed.

```
Select field1, field2, sum(table.qtd) as qtd, qtd/12 as yearmean
from table
group by field1, field2
```

Choice another name to aggregate field:

```
Select field1, field2, sum(table.qtd) as quantity, quantity/12 as yearmean
from table
group by field1, field2
```